# Ajax call before click lost in server on firefox, chrome and ie10 is ok

Tags: ajax, firefox, click

Before a click event, I have to record the click event and send it to server by ajax call.But in firefox the request is lost, the server could not get the request, seems the click is to quick to wait the ajax call completed? But IE and Chrome could. Could anyone help me on that?

PS 
1: The click is like `<a href="http://google.com"  target="_self"><span>Click me</span></a>`, when target = '_target' will open a new winodw, this is work well.

2: The ajax call url is not the same with the click href.

3: before the ajax call add a alert() the server then could receive the request.